# 2d coordinates expansion and shrinking

Tags: c++, geometry, polygon, coordinate-systems

I was trying to expand or shrink the 2d object up to K. Let's say I've a co-ordinate system like `{ {5,0}, {0,0}, {0,-5}, {5,-5}, {5,-10}, {0,-10} }` (yellow marker shape) and I want to offset every position K = 1. The resultant shape would look something like this

[image: Open shape Polygon]

As my initial approach was to find the center of the shape and increase each coordinate according to the center, the source is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEeZgQgEWTg&t=174s). But it seems like it only works on a closed symmetric shape like squares and for asymmetric shapes or open shapes, it doesn't work.

My code is given below

```
void myFun() {
        std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> co, CO;
        co = { { {5,0}, {0,0}, {0,-5}, {5,-5}, {5,-10}, {0,-10} } };
        double x = 0, y = 0;
        double n = co.size();
        for (auto it : co) {
            x += it.first; y += it.second;
        }
        std::pair<double, double> o = { x / n, y / n };
        int K = 1;
        for (auto it : co) {
            std::pair<double, double> inc = { (it.first - o.first) * K, (it.second - o.second) * K };
            CO.push_back({ o.first - inc.first, o.second - inc.second });
        }
        reverse(CO.begin(), CO.end());
        for (auto it: CO) {}
    }
```

The output co-ordinate shape is

[image]

How can I improve my approach and solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Currently the first diagram shows a figure where the upper half is enlarged, while the lower halt is shrunk. Is this intended? Also in the first diagram you have the special case that endpoints are enlarged/shrunk in one dimension, e.g. `(5, 0)` became `(5, 1)` (only y changed) while `(0, 0)` became `(-1, 1)` (both changed). Is this intentional?

Comment: Normally this is done using transformation matrices (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).
Translate center point to 0.0, then resize, then inverse translation back to original center.

Comment: first is parallel lines, and another is scaled lines. I'm not sure what you want but they are not same.

Comment: well the first I mean parallel like borders.

Comment: Your 2nd image show exactly what I would expect from scaling around the center of the object.

Comment: I'm trying to shift the (x,y) coordinates up to K where some coordinate positions will shrink and others will expand. Here, my intended output positions are in the first image whereas the 2nd image just amplified the shape not shift each positions

Comment: What's exactly meant by `K` ?

Comment: You might want to check out the links in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3436158/12861639

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways for you to achieve what you are after:

1. simply scaling around a point. Take all the coordinates that make up the shape and scale them. To make that happen around a certain point, use the usual approach consisting of those steps: 1. Translate such that (0,0) is the point to scale around, 2, Scale and 3. Translate back. That can easily be done with [transform matrices](https://www.cs.trinity.edu/%7Ejhowland/cs2322/2d/2d/).
2. Offset each point. That is far more complicated, since it requires you to define an In- / Outside of the shape. Event though this is a description for bezier curves, [here](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#offsetting) you can find a good and illustrative description of the approach. Basically you need to find some kind of normal vector for each Point in the shape and offset it on a fixed amount in that direction.

Maybe there are other way and combinations of the both above which finally snap each point on the grid by rounding.